# How to IP forward only between 2 interfaces out of 3 installed?

Tags: networking, routing, nic

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

There are 3 NIC on my PC but I wish to do ip forward only on 2 of them that act as a router. The 3rd NIC need to be separated from the other 2 and not be able to see the transportation of the router.

Is there a way to operate ip_forward only on 2 NIC and not on all 3?
Could I use routing table instead to do the same instead of ip_forward?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iptables`.

Let's say eth0 and eth1 will be the routing NICs and eth2 will not route anything.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -j DROP
```

The forwarded packets incoming (`-o`) and outgoing (`-i`) through eth2 will be dropped. Communication between PC and eth2 LAN will not be affected.

If you want to make these rules persistent after a reboot install iptables-persistent (`sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`) and run the following to save the rules:

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```